# JPA Carga de una lista en datatable

Tags: java, mysql, primefaces

Buenos dias,

En un metodo estoy trayendo dos listas con el parámetro orden de trabajo (`idOrdentrabajo`) la primer lista me carga de forma correcta en un datatable pero la segunda lista me arroja el siguiente error.

> Información:   ERROR: Query argument idOrdentrabajo not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.

```
    public void listenerOrdenTrabajoProductoYMateriales() {

    //System.out.println("id " + ordentrabajo.getId());

    String namedQuery = "OrdentrabajoProducto.findByIdOrdenTrabajo";
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    parametros.put("idOrdentrabajo", ordentrabajo);
    ordentrabajoProductoList = ordentrabajoProductoFacade.findByNamedQuery(namedQuery, parametros);

    String namedQuery1 = "OrdentrabajoMaterial.findByIdOrdenTrabajo";
    Map<String, Object> parametros1 = new HashMap<>();
    parametros.put("idOrdentrabajo", ordentrabajo);        
    ordentrabajoMaterialist = ordentrabajoMaterialFacade.findByNamedQuery(namedQuery1, parametros1);


}
```

Comment: Se agradeceria que se cambiara el nombre de la pregunta ya que el tema que esta preguntando es sobre JPA y el encabezado de la pregunta hace alusion a JSF

Comment: Por favor, tambien agrega el codigo de las consultas y las entidades que usas en dichas consultas

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate

```
String namedQuery = "OrdentrabajoProducto.findByIdOrdenTrabajo";
Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
parametros.put("idOrdentrabajo", ordentrabajo);
ordentrabajoProductoList = ordentrabajoProductoFacade.findByNamedQuery(namedQuery, parametros);

String namedQuery1 = "OrdentrabajoMaterial.findByIdOrdenTrabajo";
Map<String, Object> parametros1 = new HashMap<>();
parametros.put("idOrdentrabajo", ordentrabajo);        
ordentrabajoMaterialist = ordentrabajoMaterialFacade.findByNamedQuery(namedQuery1, parametros1);
```

Pasaste por parámetro, el map parametros1, pero no lo asignaste sino que dejaste pegado el copy de la linea de arriba

parametros.put("idOrdentrabajo", ordentrabajo);

entonces en parámetros1, esta llegando el hash map vació

Comment: Me podria explicar mejor  la verdad quede un poco confuso soy nuevo y no tengo mucha experiencia en el tema

Comment: En el segundo bloque defines `parametros1` pero nunca haces `parametros1.put` lo has dejado con `parametros.put`

Answer (score 0):

Definiste en tu clase el attr @NamedNativeQuery para definir el SP?

Si no, probá usando el Native SQL en la llamada

```
String namedQuery = "CALL OrdentrabajoMaterial.findByIdOrdenTrabajo(:idOrdentrabajo);"
```

Comment: No funciono amigo igual muchas gracias.

Comment: Los querys Nativos ocupan mucha memoria en java ya que se construyen y destruyen.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error en el código, pones esto:

```
String namedQuery1 = "OrdentrabajoMaterial.findByIdOrdenTrabajo";
Map<String, Object> parametros1 = new HashMap<>();
parametros.put("idOrdentrabajo", ordentrabajo);        
ordentrabajoMaterialist = ordentrabajoMaterialFacade.findByNamedQuery(namedQuery1, parametros1);
```

Pero debería ser:

```
String namedQuery1 = "OrdentrabajoMaterial.findByIdOrdenTrabajo";
Map<String, Object> parametros1 = new HashMap<>();
parametros1.put("idOrdentrabajo", ordentrabajo);        
ordentrabajoMaterialist = ordentrabajoMaterialFacade.findByNamedQuery(namedQuery1, parametros1);
```

En la tercera linea estabas usando parametros y no parametros1.